# Change background color of the cell if another cell in this row contains the value

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

I have this list and I need to put the condition so that the background colors on column "A" will be red if the item is sold

Comment: Can you show the conditional format rule you tried?

Comment: In Excel I would try Conditional Formatting, but not sure it is the same in Google Sheets.

Comment: conditional format.  applies to `$A:$A` and the custom formula of `=$C1="Sold"`

Answer (score 1):

As what Scott Craner already mentioned in the comments, you would need to use conditional formatting under `Format`

#### Sample:

[image: sample]

#### Reference:

- [Use conditional formatting rules in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cexample)